# How to create tab within tab in android application? In other words, how to create parent tab and child tab?

Tags: android

I just began study android app.
I want to create app to have tab.
Please teach it.

Comment: This is not a tutorial website.

Comment: Just search for Tabhost or TabLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a parent tab in XML file,and embed a child tab in parent tab.